# Dynamically add values ​of an object into inputs in two rows using array method forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have an object with several keys and values, I would like to add its values ​​to inputs corresponding to the key of the object. But I want to do this dynamically and generically using a method of array (`forEach`) in a two line code.

My object:

```js
const createNewBill = {
  type: "Hôtel et logement",
  name: "bill test",
  date: "2020-04-08",
  amount: 130,
  pct: 25,
  file: 'hotel.jpg'
}
```

I found this way but it is not dynamic and scalable :

```js
document.getByTestId("expense-type").value = createNewBill.type
document.getByTestId("expense-name").value = createNewBill.name
document.getByTestId("datepicker").value = createNewBill.datepicker
document.getByTestId("amount").value = createNewBill.amount
document.getByTestId("pct").value = createNewBill.pct
document.getByTestId("file").value = createNewBill.file
```

Comment: Have you consider using ReactJS, Angular or any other lib that facilitate the view/binding for you?

Comment: @XavierGarnier I'm starting REACT in a while, for the moment I'm learning vanilla JS! But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const createNewBill = {
  type: "Hôtel et logement",
  name: "bill test",
  date: "2020-04-08",
  amount: 130,
 }

 Object.keys(createNewBill).forEach(key => {
   document.getElementById(key).value = createNewBill[key]
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <input id="type" />
        <input id="name" />
        <input id="date" />
        <input id="amount" />
    </body>
</html>
```

One solution that I can suggest if you could change the keys of the object to the same ones in your HTML IDs or vice versa.

```
Object.keys(createNewBill).forEach(key => {
  document.getByTestId(key).value = createNewBill[key]
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was helpful !

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that something like could work:

```js
Object.entries(createNewBill).forEach(([key, value]) =>
  document.getByTestId(key).value = value);
```

But it would require you to rename `expense-type` into `type` and same for `expense-name` and `datepicker`. Or to use the same prefix for all the other ones.

Anyway, I strongly recommend you to use a lib like ReactJS, Angular or anything that will make this king of things easier for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method along with the [`Template literals (Template strings)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax.

```
const createNewBill = {
  type: "Hôtel et logement",
  name: "bill test",
  date: "2020-04-08",
  amount: 130,
  pct: 25,
  file: 'hotel.jpg'
};

Object.keys(createNewBill).forEach(key => {
    document.getByTestId(`expense-${key}`).value = createNewBill[key]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips with Template strings ! ;)